# Utility function to toggle ARIA and data attributes, and manage CSS classes on HTML dropdowns

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I have a dropdown utility function that is mostly working. The issues are with properly handling the toggling of the `data-text` and `aria` attributes for the buttons when clicking on the non-target button or outside the target element completely.

I have included my `window.addEventListener` code, but have commented it out as it is affecting the display of the `ul` sub menu elements.

I am learning vanilla JavaScript in bits and pieces, so please provide tips and solutions that are simple for a novice JS developer. Thanks.

```js
const navUtility = (() => {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-nav-toggle]");
  const containers = document.querySelectorAll("[data-nav-container]");

  if (!buttons) {
    return;
  }

  function dropdownToggleHandler() {
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
      button.addEventListener("click", toggleContainer);
    });
  }

  function toggleContainer(e) {
    toggleButtonClass(e.target);
    toggleButtonAria(e.target);
    toggleButtonDataText(e.target);
    toggleContainers(e.target);
  }

  function toggleButtonClass(button) {
    if (button.classList.contains("is-active")) {
      button.classList.remove("is-active");
    } else {
      button.classList.add("is-active");
    }
  }

  function toggleButtonAria(button) {
    const expandedValue = button.getAttribute("aria-expanded");
    const setValue = expandedValue === "true" ? "false" : "true";
    button.setAttribute("aria-expanded", setValue);
  }

  function toggleButtonDataText(button) {
    const originalValue = button.getAttribute("data-text-original");
    const swapValue = button.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
    if (swapValue === button.textContent) {
      button.textContent = button.getAttribute("data-text-original");
    } else {
      button.setAttribute("data-text-original", button.textContent);
      button.textContent = button.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
    }
  }

  function toggleContainers(button) {
    const parent = button.closest("[data-nav-container]");
    parent.classList.toggle("is-expanded");
    document.querySelectorAll(".is-expanded").forEach(function(parentExpanded) {
      if (parentExpanded !== parent) {
        parentExpanded.classList.remove("is-expanded");
      }
    });
  }

  dropdownToggleHandler();

  /* window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    containers.forEach((container) => {
      if (e.target !== container) {
        container.classList.remove("is-expanded");
      }
    });
  }); */
})();
```

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
}

nav>ul {
  width: 21rem;
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: max-height 200ms ease-out;
}

nav.is-expanded>ul {
  max-height: 4000px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav class="" data-nav-container="want-to-navigation" aria-label="Site tools navigation">
  <button aria-expanded="false" class="" data-nav-toggle="want-to-navigation" data-text-swap="Close" data-text-original="I Want To...">Close</button>
  <ul id="want-to-navigation" class="menu">
    <li>
      <a>Apply For</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Development Permits</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Dust Suppressant</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Fire Permit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Employment</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Subdivision</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<nav class="" data-nav-container="quick-links-navigation" aria-label="Site quick links navigation">
  <button aria-expanded="false" class="" data-nav-toggle="quick-links-navigation" data-text-swap="Close" data-text-original="Quicklinks">Close</button>
  <ul id="quick-links-navigation">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Community Guide</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Notice of Development</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Workshops &amp; Courses</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Council Business</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Condition you have added in event listener of window not helping you. Instead of comparing `container` with event target element, you have to check does `container` contains event target element. If event is within `nav` just ignore else toggle `container` class list for `.is-expanded`.

Replacing

```
if (e.target !== container) {
    container.classList.remove("is-expanded");
}
```

with

```
if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
    container.classList.remove("is-expanded");
}
```

would solve your problem.

---

**With quick fix**

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  const navUtility = (() => {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-nav-toggle]");
    const containers = document.querySelectorAll("[data-nav-container]");
    
    if (!buttons) {
      return;
    }
    
    function dropdownToggleHandler() {
      buttons.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener("click", toggleContainer);
      });
    }
    
    function toggleContainer(e) {
      toggleButtonClass(e.target);
      toggleButtonAria(e.target);
      toggleButtonDataText(e.target);
      
      
      toggleContainers(e.target);
    }
    
    function toggleButtonClass(button) {
      if (button.classList.contains("is-active")) {
        button.classList.remove("is-active");
      } else {
        button.classList.add("is-active");
      }
    }
    
    function toggleButtonAria(button) {
      const expandedValue = button.getAttribute("aria-expanded");
      const setValue = expandedValue === "true" ? "false" : "true";
      button.setAttribute("aria-expanded", setValue);
    }
    
    function toggleButtonDataText(button) {
      const originalValue = button.getAttribute("data-text-original");
      const swapValue = button.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
      if (swapValue === button.textContent) {
        button.textContent = button.getAttribute("data-text-original");
      } else {
        button.setAttribute("data-text-original", button.textContent);
        button.textContent = button.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
      }
    }
    
    function toggleContainers(button) {
      const parent = button.closest("[data-nav-container]");
      parent.classList.toggle("is-expanded");
      document.querySelectorAll(".is-expanded").forEach(function(parentExpanded) {
        if (parentExpanded !== parent) {
          parentExpanded.classList.remove("is-expanded");
        }
      });
    }
    
    dropdownToggleHandler();
    
    window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      containers.forEach((container) => {
        if (!container.contains(e.target)) {
          container.classList.remove("is-expanded");
        }
      });
    });
  })();
})
```

```css
nav {
  position: relative;
}

nav>ul {
  width: 21rem;
  max-height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
  transition: max-height 200ms ease-out;
}

nav.is-expanded>ul {
  max-height: 4000px;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav tabindex="-1"  class="" data-nav-container="want-to-navigation" aria-label="Site tools navigation">
  <button aria-expanded="false" class="" data-nav-toggle="want-to-navigation" data-text-swap="Close" data-text-original="I Want To...">Close</button>
  <ul id="want-to-navigation" class="menu">
    <li>
      <a>Apply For</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Development Permits</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Dust Suppressant</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Fire Permit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Employment</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Subdivision</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<nav tabindex="-1" class="" data-nav-container="quick-links-navigation" aria-label="Site quick links navigation">
  <button aria-expanded="false" class="" data-nav-toggle="quick-links-navigation" data-text-swap="Close" data-text-original="Quicklinks">Close</button>
  <ul id="quick-links-navigation">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Community Guide</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Notice of Development</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Workshops &amp; Courses</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Council Business</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This will fix the hiding issue, you need to change the button caption accordingly.

[update]

###### code minimised to avoid lengthy post

**Though this works fine you must try `onBlur` event to handle such activity rather than checking click on the whole document for the target element.**

You can use a label instead of a button since a label allows you to associate with other elements with for attribute.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",handleDomOnLoad);function handleDomOnLoad(a){(()=>{let a=document.querySelectorAll("[data-nav-toggle]"),b=document.querySelectorAll("[data-nav-container]");function c(a){d(a.target),e(a.target),f(a.target),g(a.target)}function d(a){a.classList.contains("is-active")?a.classList.remove("is-active"):a.classList.add("is-active")}function e(a){let b=a.getAttribute("aria-expanded");a.setAttribute("aria-expanded","true"===b?"false":"true")}function f(a){a.getAttribute("data-text-original");let b=a.getAttribute("data-text-swap");b===a.textContent?a.textContent=a.getAttribute("data-text-original"):(a.setAttribute("data-text-original",a.textContent),a.textContent=a.getAttribute("data-text-swap"))}function g(a){let b=a.closest("[data-nav-container]");b.classList.toggle("is-expanded"),document.querySelectorAll(".is-expanded").forEach(function(a){a!==b&&a.classList.remove("is-expanded")})}

function handleOnBlur(e) {
  if (!e.currentTarget.contains(e.relatedTarget))
    e.target.classList.remove("is-expanded");
};

document.querySelectorAll('li a[href]').forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  console.log(e.target.textContent);
  document.querySelectorAll('nav').forEach(n=>n.classList.remove("is-expanded")); //can fetch specific parent by traversing
}))

,a&&(a.forEach(a=>{a.addEventListener("click",c)}),

document.querySelectorAll("[data-nav-container]").forEach(
  a=>{
    a.addEventListener("blur",handleOnBlur)
  }
)

)})()}
```

```css
*{ font-family: sans-serif; }
nav { position: relative; background-color: #cfcfcf; margin: 5px; padding: 8px 16px; border-radius: 5px; display: inline-block; }
nav>ul { padding: 8px 16px; width: 21rem; position: absolute; right: auto; left: 0; z-index: 5; visibility: hidden; background-color: #cfcfcf78; transition: max-height 200ms ease-out; border-radius: 5px; }
nav.is-expanded>ul { height: auto; visibility: visible; }
nav ul li { margin: 0px; list-style-type: none; }
nav li ul li { padding:10px; }
```

```html
<nav tabindex="-1" id="nav1" data-nav-container="want-to-navigation" aria-label="Site tools navigation">
  <label aria-expanded="false" for='nav1' class="" data-nav-toggle="want-to-navigation" data-text-swap="Close" data-text-original="I Want To...">Close</label>
  <ul id="want-to-navigation" class="menu">
    <li>
      <a>Apply For</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Development Permits</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dust Suppressant</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Fire Permit</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Employment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subdivision</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I have refactored my code using your `window.addEventListener` function. I implemented `container.firstElementChild.classList.remove("is-active"); container.firstElementChild.setAttribute("aria-expanded", false); container.firstElementChild.textContent = container.firstElementChild.getAttribute("data-text-original");` to reset the button attributes and class in the `forEach` loop. Could you clarify the `onBlur` suggestion?